# reset bootstrap radio button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

this has got to be a duplicate question but I can't find the answer.  how do you reset the bootstrap radio buttons?

according to the documentation it is reset but it doesn't see to do anything I also tried using jquery to change it but nothing.

```
$('#Reset').click(function(){
$('#option1').button('reset');
  $("#option1").prop('checked', true);
});
```

here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/m1jryanh/ I am clicking on a different button then hit the reset button hoping it will reset but it does not.

Comment: I am assuming that on clicking on reset you want to restore the preselection i.e. #option1 should be selected again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just perform a click on `#option1`.

```
$('#Reset').click(function(){
  $("#option1").click();
});
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1jryanh/6/).

Comment: The problem with this approach is if the `click()` method is implemented and more things are done

Answer (score 6):

**Unselecting All Options**

If you are referring to updating the UI, you can explicitly remove the `active` classes from all of the buttons (or in your case labels) themselves :

```
$('#Reset').click(function(){
   // Explicitly uncheck all of your radio buttons
   $('[data-toggle="buttons"] :radio').prop('checked', false);
   // Select all label elements within your toggle and remove the active class
   $('[data-toggle="buttons"] label').removeClass('active');
});
```

You can [see this in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/m1jryanh/9/) and demonstrated below :

[image]

**Resetting to the First Option**

Likewise, if you want to set it to it's initial option, you can simply trigger a `click` event for the first element :

```
$('#Reset').click(function(){
   // Explicitly uncheck all of your radio buttons
   $('[data-toggle="buttons"] :radio').prop('checked', false);
   // Select all label elements within your toggle and remove the active class
   $('[data-toggle="buttons"] label').removeClass('active');

   // Set the first one as checked and selected
   $('[data-toggle="buttons"] :radio:first').addClass('active');
   // Do the same thing for the active indicator
   $('[data-toggle="buttons"] label:first').addClass('active');
});
```

You can [see this option in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/m1jryanh/10/) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: A one-liner (untested for 3, works for 4): `$('[data-toggle="buttons"]').button('toggle').find(':checked').prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `active` class and uncheck radio button like following.

```
$('#Reset').click(function () {
    $('.btn-group :radio').prop('checked', false);
    $('.btn-group .active').removeClass('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m1jryanh/8/)**